# Can I create XLSX files via SSIS Execute SQL Task with "Always Create Backup" disabled?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, xlsx

When I run Execute SQL Task to create an xlsx file, the file's "Always create backup" option is always enabled in the Save As > Tools > General Properties options (where you can set a password to open or modify and set as read-only).  This causes "Backup of ..." files to be created anytime the file is saved.

```
Execute SQL Task properties:
    TimeOut: 0
    CodePage: 1252
    TypeConversionMode: Allowed
    ConnectionType: EXCEL
    SQLSourceType: Direct input
    SQLStatement: CREATE TABLE no_backup ([testing] LONGTEXT, [no auto] LONGTEXT)

EXCEL Connection Manager Properties:
    ConnectionString: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                      Data Source=C:\FILEPATH\FILENAME.xlsx;
                      Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES";
    ExcelVersionNumber: 4
```

When creating a xlsx file manually in Excel, this option is not enabled.  I cannot find settings or properties to make this the default in SSIS.

Is there a way to set the connection string or properties somewhere to create xlsx files with "Always Create Backup" DISABLED so multiple files aren't generated everytime an original file is saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like SSIS creating Excel documents always sets this way.  No way to change it.
Only way to prevent it is create a template file with the correct settings and copy to a new named file each time.